# ASP.NET / Entity Framework Format string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I just want to ask for sample of string format cause this code doesn't work for me

```
    public int QueueId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string QueueNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0}{1:000}", Name ?? "?", QueueId);
        }
        set{ }
    }
```

I want to render the name I enter + the primary key of it, but all I see is

Sample data in database :

1. Carlo000
2. Alexa000

I want it to be :

1. Carlo001
2. Alexa002

Comment: Did you check QueueId value when insert to Database? May be it is still 0

Comment: ID is auto increment right? it's not zero

Comment: can you post your code where it show QueueNumber Carlo000 ?

Comment: I just simulated your code and your formatting is working fine given QueueId is not 0.   Your issue is either as Hien suggested and your QueueId is 0 in the database, or your aren't actually pulling the values from the database for the field and it's default value is 0 since it's an int.